# Upgraded to 16.04 and now getting error message

Tags: boot, upgrade, lvm, 16.04

After successfully upgraded to 16.04, I am now getting this message whilst booting
`lvmetad not active yet, using direct access`

Comment: I have a similar problem - this message appears briefly after logging in to the desktop.  And then I get thrown back to the log-in screen.  Console access (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F6) works OK.
I've hunted around a little:

 - tried removing `.Xauthority`.  No benefit 
 - tried `apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`, and `apt-get autoremove`.  No benefit (although the log-in screen is different)

Comment: Unlike Chrisky I am unable to login at all. After grub I get the same mesage as Kitcho `lvmetad not active yet, using direct access`. I can not execute any command. My root partition was lvm.

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

This is an inofensive message and you should not worry about it.

If you do 'man lvmetad' you'll find that it is a daemon that caches disk metadata. If this daemon is not available, lvm will read the metadata from the disk. This may be a problem with very complex systems with hundreds of volumes, but it is not for a desktop.

Every message that says it has been solved by touching grub or after installing some packages, has probably solved by upgrading the system and recreating the grub configuration.

This is a very very low priority bug and was there in Ubuntu and Debian for a while. Probably will dissapear in a upgrade without doing anything.

I've got that message for a while and without any adverse condition.

People complaining to be unable to login are being affected by another error and should continue checking the logs to find it.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Kyle in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761541/ubuntu-server-16-04-wont-boot-after-installation?rq=1), you can stop this blocking your interactive ttys from appearing with the following:

> I managed to resolve this for my machines by adjusting the grub
>   configuration like so:
>
> In `/etc/default/grub`, change:
>
> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to 
>   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"` 
>   Then add this line:
>   `GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console serial"` 
>   Run sudo update-grub and reboot for the changes to take effect.

---

Comment: This just sends logs somewhere else, maybe impacting useful log reporting. Solves nothing regarding what is being logged.

Comment: In the thread you mention they solve a video issue by enabling nomodeset, it is absolutely unrelated to the messages.

Comment: You are correct, but the I believe the *problem* OP is experiencing is absolutely unrelated to the messages, beyond the messages appearance being a symptom. The *problem* is that the TTY this message appears in is non-interactive (ie the user cannot login). What I believe OP is asking for, is an interactive tty to appear immediately instead of having to manually switch to one using ctrl-alt-f[1-7] every time they boot. Now, fair enough I may be reading more into the issue than required, however this question ranked highly in the google results when I was trying to resolve the issue detailed