# Ubuntu server 16.04 won't boot after installation

Tags: boot, server, 16.04

I've just installed ubuntu server 16.04 but it won't boot.
Here's the only thing I get on screen:

> lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit
>
> lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit
>
> /dev/mapper/server--vg-root: clean xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks

"xxx" are some large numbers
I can't even use the command line so I'm stucked. Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761056/upgraded-to-16-04-and-now-getting-error-message). Add your own information to the question. If you have a live-usb you should have no problem accessing the files.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, since the original one shows a harmless message but boots, but this one has the harmless message but doesn't boot.

Comment: The lvmetad logs shown are irrelevant to the issue, nomodeset is used to configure your video output, lvmetad is related to the storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve this for my machines by adjusting the grub configuration like so:

In `/etc/default/grub`, change:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"`
Then add this line:

`GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console serial"`
Run `sudo update-grub` and `reboot` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, fwiw this should be the accepted answer because it actually solves the problem. I discovered this answer 5 mins after posting a similar thread (of course) - feel free to post your answer in there, and I'll clean up my attribution post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/973339/how-do-i-force-ubuntu-server-to-switch-to-an-interactive-tty-after-boot/973343#973343

Answer (score 1):

Although I doesn't actually solve my problem, I managed to "bypass" it using another tty (Crtl-alt-F2) and now I can use my server