# How do I force Ubuntu Server to switch to an interactive tty after boot?

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, tty

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04 guest in KVM (on a non-ubuntu host)

When it finishes booting, it displays a non-interactive screen with a couple of non-critical boot messages[1], and I must manually switch to an interactive tty to login (virt-manager interface: Send Key -> Ctrl+Alt+Fx). This is a little bit of a problem, particularly if I have a colleague who's unaware of the issue try and get access to the machine.

Is there a way to either force my display to an interactive tty after booting, or suppress the messages screen?

---

[1]:
For search help, the non-critical messages are:

```
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
/dev/mapper/host-vg-root: clean 67347/887696 files, 668202/3544064 blocks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Of course, a week of banging my head, I ask the question and discover the answer 5 mins later...)

Thanks to @Kyle in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761541/ubuntu-server-16-04-wont-boot-after-installation?rq=1)

> I managed to resolve this for my machines by adjusting the grub
>   configuration like so:
>
> In `/etc/default/grub`, change:
>
> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to 
>   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"` 
>   Then add this line:
>   `GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console serial"`
>
> Run sudo update-grub and reboot for the changes to take effect.